# Option Menu From Fragment in action bar in android

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabactivity, android-actionbar

In my application i am having a TabActivity in which i am using One Activity which has two fragments.Both Fragments have options menu.But these Optionss menu are not showing up in the Action Bar.
I have also put items in menu to "showAsAction".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set [setHasOptionsMenu](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setHasOptionsMenu%28boolean%29) to true.

Comment: sir i  already done this ,but my problem is that my fragments contained with in an activity which is uder TabActivity .